# how detect rgb image format really is gray?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

i have image processing program with opencv c++.
inmy program two preprocessing path is for 2 type of gray level images and color images.
but some times i get images is graylevel but store in RGB format means when look image is gray but this image have 3 channel.

how i can detect a rgb image format is really colored or gray ?

Comment: Since grey is defined as having no saturation, you could convert to a colorspace that has a *Saturation* component (e.g. HSL) and check that the Saturation channel is zero, or that its maximum is very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly all colors of grey have `red == green == blue`. Simply checking that red green and blue values are `+10 or -10` should do the trick.

If instead you wish for a particular form of gray, you can check out [this website](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/gray-color.htm) to see the relevant colours of gray that can be formed or experiment yourself on a RGB input portal.

Answer (score 6):

You can go through the pixels and check that their value for R, G and B are the same everytime.

```
cv::Mat image;  // your image with type CV_8UC3
bool grayscale = true;
for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
    cv::Vec3b* ptr = image.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
        if(!(ptr[j][0] == ptr[j][1] && ptr[j][0] == ptr[j][2])) {
            grayscale = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!grayscale)
        break;
}
```